# showdialog() crash on 32 bit application .net 4.0 WPF

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, clr

I am creating an add-in for an application in windows for which i am using c++, c# and CLR.
Now the problem is that while add-in  is running fine with 64bit version of application.It crashes with the 32 bit application at the following code snippet.

I am using windows 7 64bit system.

```
try
{
    WindowInteropHelper WndInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    WndInteropHelper.Owner = pParentWnd;
    this.pParentWnd = pParentWnd;

    this.ShowDialog();  // It crashes exactly here.

}
catch (Exception ex)
```

For the 32 bit add in .net 3.5, 4.0 have been used, where as for 64 bit .net 4.5 was used.

I have tried to debug the program but it crashes the moment control goes to this.showDialog().

No exception is caught, however when I enable exceptions in `Debug`->`Exceptions`, following exceptions are thrown.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

followed by

> Access violation.

please do post if you need further information.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please post the full exception details.

Comment: First-chance exception at 0x757bc41f in application.exe: 0xE0434F4D: 0xe0434f4d.
First-chance exception at 0x522f9839 (mfc100u.dll) in application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000009c.

These were the exceptions thrown.

Comment: maybe the original window is in 64 bit?

Comment: @AminBudianto could you please elaborate, i am new to c# don't have much idea about how c# and .net works.

Comment: Why assign a value to itself? `this.pParentWnd = pParentWnd;`

Comment: I am not familiar with Interop. Maybe you can just check if the original window you want to open is build in 32 bit?